# Add programatically and precisely time to system-time

Tags: delphi, winapi, clock

I wrote a speedhack for a game, that bypasses a specific time. The game lets you wait 5 minutes. It grabs as it looks first the system time and when the timer (5 minutes) is done, it compares the system time again and checks if the delay is 5 minutes.

**pseudocode for game:**

```
var t = GetSystemTime();
WaitMinutes(5);
if (GetSystemTime() - t != 5000)
{
  Error;
}
```

I get it bypassed manually like that:

Wait until the game waited 1 minute, so that there is a waiting time left of 4 minutes. Change at exact that point the systemclock + 4 minutes.

Then speedhack with CE or my tool the game.

However, I want to do this programatically and it seems to be not accurate enough how I do it.

```
  GetLocalTime(systimecurr);
  wmin := systimecurr.wMinute + iWaitingTime;
  whour := systimecurr.wHour;
  wday := systimecurr.wDay;
  wsecs := systimecurr.wSecond + iWaitingTimeSeconds;



  if wsecs >= 60 then
  begin
    wsecs := wsecs mod 60;
    wmin := wmin + 1;
  end;

  if wmin >= 60 then
  begin
    wmin := wmin mod 60;
    whour := whour + 1;
    if whour >= 24 then
    begin
      wday := wday + 1;
    end;
  end;

  SetDateTime(systimecurr.wYear, systimecurr.wMonth, wday, wHour,
              wmin, wsecs, systimecurr.wMilliseconds);
```

I know that this can't be precise but I actually don't know how to do it perfectly.

**Again: I need to add time (for example 5 minutes) to the system Clock precisly to the offset it got retrieved!**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wonder which game are you talking here. There are not many games who actually use system clock for its events. I guess it is probably one of those "perma games" as they sometimes tend to call them where game is capable of quickly simulating events for the time passed since the last time game was running. Anyway I would personally disadvise you from changing your system time rapidly. Why? By doing so you can cause some strange behavior from Windows. For instace you prevent windows from actually knowing which file was accessed last.

Comment: Also some Anti Virus software programs might mark your program as being potentially dangerous and quarantine it because of it since some viruses were known to programmatically change system clock in order to try and remove its spreading traces.

Comment: So in order to avoid possible problems you might at least want to consider running your game inside a virtual environment to prevent your cheating approach from affecting your host system.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I got it to work. There is actually a huge time between the little code :D

QueryPerformanceCounter solved it!

Here the correct code:

```
  GetLocalTime(systimecurr);
  **QueryPerformanceFrequency(freq);
  QueryPerformanceCounter(startTime);**
  wmin := systimecurr.wMinute + iWaitingTime;
  whour := systimecurr.wHour;
  wday := systimecurr.wDay;
  wsecs := systimecurr.wSecond + iWaitingTimeSeconds;
  wmilli := systimecurr.wMilliseconds;

  if wsecs >= 60 then
  begin
    wsecs := wsecs mod 60;
    wmin := wmin + 1;
  end;

  if wmin >= 60 then
  begin
    wmin := wmin mod 60;
    whour := whour + 1;
    if whour >= 24 then
    begin
      wday := wday + 1;
    end;
  end;

  **QueryPerformanceCounter(endTime);**

  **wmilli := wmilli + ((endTime - startTime) * 1000 div freq);**

  SetDateTime(systimecurr.wYear, systimecurr.wMonth, wday, whour,
              wMin, wsecs, wMilli);

  showmessage(inttostr(wmilli));
```

Comment: Note that you need admin privileges to change the system clock. The [`SYSTEMTIME` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950.aspx) tells you how to perform arithmetic on date/time values, you do not need to resort to decoding the individual components. Convert `SYSTEMTIME` to a `ULARGE_INTEGER` using `FILETIME`, increment/decrement it as needed (in 100-nanosecond intervals) and convert back to `SYSTEMTIME`.